# Python KeyError Parsing Database Results

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, loops

I have a script which parses a DB call then creates a report. It has been working great until the new fiscal year started this weekend. Not sure why that matters here but it does.

Using Python 3.6

Data format `wk = (('Chittendon', '18028656387', 1),)`

The only change here is that because of the new fiscal year the `yr` variable may be blank now

Code that is breaking:

```
data = {(name, n): [y, 0, 0] for name, n, y in yr}
for name, n, w in wk:
    data[name, n][2] = w
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ace/Desktop/IPNV/KP_App/FML/mail_service/vcc_resource.py", line 172, in <module>
    pooh = Main()
  File "C:/Users/Ace/Desktop/IPNV/KP_App/FML/mail_service/vcc_resource.py", line 144, in Main
    data[name, n][2] = w
KeyError: ('Chittendon', '18028656387')
```

Like I mentioned this has been working perfectly until today. Not sure what changed.

Comment: How does data look like? Is it multiIndex?

Comment: How it appears in the `wk` variable. I posted it in the question

Comment: wk is not a dict, it a tuple. You can access it's values with the appropriate index rather than values.

Comment: I don't understand why it has been working for the past six months then

Comment: I just saw I left a piece out of the question. going to edit in now

Comment: Well, that looks better. print data just before the loop and make sure that the requested key actually exist there as it seems that the key you are looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah the problem must be here. It is a weird time of year. The year to date data will be blank now, while the week to date will have data

Comment: Data is printing blank

Comment: Also, in order to avoid from error to happen in this situation you could do: `data.get((name, n),'default')`, this way you can return a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `yr` is blank then your `data` variable will be an empty dictionary `{}`. This will cause a key error when you try to access it because obviously the keys don't exist.

```
>>> yr = []
>>> data = {(name, n): [y, 0, 0] for name, n, y in yr}
>>> data
{}
```

You need to test for that or provide a default value of some sort.

One way to handle this is to use `data.get()` rather than direct key lookup since `get()` offers the possibility of a default instead of a key error:

```
d.get(('Chittendon', '18028656386'), "somedefault")
```

EDIT:

Looking again(maybe after an edit), it looks like you are assigning new values  to data based on a key which may or may not exist. The error isn't happening because you are trying to assign to a non-existing key, which is perfectly fine, but you are trying to first access index 2 of the key. This causes the error when the key doesn't exist. You could for example do this:

```
data[name, n] = [1, 2, 3]
```

even if `[name, n]` isn't an existing key in `data`

Putting this together, you can wrap this in a try/catch block that will let you act appropriately in both cases:

```
for name, n, w in wk:    
    try:
        data[name, n][2] = w
    except KeyError:
        data[name, n] = ['some default', 'another default', w]
```

Comment: I did not vote you down, I think your answer is right I am just trying to figure out how I am going to implement it

Comment: Thanks @Joe - it sure would be nice if people were a little more helpful when down voting.

Comment: The comprehension that is a part of the data variable was borrowed from someone on here. Its a little over my head I think that is why I can't seem to figure this out. Still trying to figure out what a default would look like

Comment: I ended up just wrapping the `yr` variable in an `if` test. I think it is working now. I will mark this as correct. thanks for the help